# Get polar equation from cartesian equation

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I have this equation: $x^4 + y^4 = x^2 + y^2$ and I need to convert it to a polar one...

I have tried and the result is
$$r = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^4\theta + \sin^4\theta}}$$

Is this ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine, though there is also the point $r=0$, i.e. $(0,0)$.

Here is a picture, with the curve passing through the eight obvious points.

[image]